# in R, customize names of columns created by dcast.data.table

Tags: r, data.table, pivot-table, reshape2

I am new to `reshape2` and `data.table` and trying to learn the syntax.

I have a `data.table` that I want to cast from multiple rows per grouping variable(s) to one row per grouping variable(s).  For simplicity, let's make it a table of customers, some of whom share addresses.

```
library(data.table)

# Input table:
cust <- data.table(name=c("Betty","Joe","Frank","Wendy","Sally"),
                   address=c(rep("123 Sunny Rd",2), 
                             rep("456 Cloudy Ln",2),
                                 "789 Windy Dr"))
```

I want the output to have the following format:

```
# Desired output looks like this:
(out <- data.table(address=c("123 Sunny Rd","456 Cloudy Ln","789 Windy Dr"),
                   cust_1=c("Betty","Frank","Sally"),
                   cust_2=c("Joe","Wendy",NA)) )

#          address cust_1 cust_2
# 1:  123 Sunny Rd  Betty    Joe
# 2: 456 Cloudy Ln  Frank  Wendy
# 3:  789 Windy Dr  Sally     NA
```

I would like columns for cust_1...cust_n where n is the max customers per address.  I don't really care about the order--whether Joe is cust_1 and Betty is cust_2 or vice versa.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Just pushed a commit](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/25a74dfd8b738e5e5556144d38713b6b003a56f2) to `data.table v1.9.5`. `dcast` now

- allows casting on multiple `value.var` columns and multiple `fun.aggregate` functions
- understands undefined variables/expressions in formula

With this, we can do:

```
dcast(cust, address ~ paste0("cust", cust[, seq_len(.N), 
          by=address]$V1), value.var="name")
#          address cust1 cust2
# 1:  123 Sunny Rd Betty   Joe
# 2: 456 Cloudy Ln Frank Wendy
# 3:  789 Windy Dr Sally    NA
```

Answer (score 5):

```
# My attempt:
setkey(cust,address)
x <- cust[,list(name, addr_cust_num=rank(name,ties.method="random")), by=address])
x[,addr_cust_num:=paste0("cust_",addr_cust_num)]
y <- dcast.data.table(x, address ~ addr_cust_num, value.var="name")
y
```

Note that I had to `paste0` the "cust_" prefix.  Before I added that step, I was using `setnames(y, names(y), sub("(\\d+)","cust_\\1",names(y)) )` which seemed a clunkier (but probably faster) solution.

Wondering if there is a better way to do the prefixing.

---

Alternatively, you could just add the column directly to `cust` *by reference*:

```
# no need to set key
cust[, cust := paste("cust", seq_len(.N), sep="_"), by=address]
dcast.data.table(cust, address ~ cust, value.var="name")
#          address cust_1 cust_2
# 1:  123 Sunny Rd  Betty    Joe
# 2: 456 Cloudy Ln  Frank  Wendy
# 3:  789 Windy Dr  Sally     NA
```

Comment: I've added a very similar version, but I agree it would be great if we could avoid the first step. Could you please file an issue [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table)? Thanks.